# AWS credentials leakege on live app on playstore

Tags: amazon-web-services, android-security

I uploaded first version of the app 1.0 with hard-coded AWS credentials in app. For this security violation I received email from google play store teams for security leakage. Next time I uploaded app where AWS credentials are not hard-coded but when I upload a new apk version, I received email from Google for same AWS credentials leakage corresponding to apk version 1. My current version of app is 2.0 but the mail I got from Google corresponds to apk version 1. This can be an issue or can ignore this mail

1.0 - AWS credentials were hard-coded
1.2 to 2.0 - AWS credentials are not hard-coded